# Геттеры и сеттеры Jackson перебивают методы родителя

Tags: java, jackson

Есть класс:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Children extends Parent {

private final String id;
private List<String> names;

public VirtualCondition(
        @JsonProperty("id") String id,
        @JsonProperty("names") List<String> names) {
    this.id = id;
    this.names = names;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public List<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}
}
```

И его родитель:

```
public abstract class Parent {

private List<String> names;

public Parent() { }


public List<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(List<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}
}
```

Когда на готовых объектах пытаюсь получить getNames() получаю null. Хотя по коду я получаю объеты, а потом выполняю метод setNames().

У меня такое чувство, то Jackson создает гетеры и сетеры свои. А когда я у объекта их вызываю, то дергаю методы родителя.

Такое может быть? Как разрешить такую проблему? Мне надо именно под "names" выводить в ендпоинте.

Comment: `Хотя по коду я получаю объеты, а потом выполняю ...` А зачем рассказывать? Покажите лучше пример кода

Comment: @defaultlocale много придется лишнего выносить в тему, DAO, Контроллеры...

Comment: Нужно попробовать убрать все лишнее и составить минимальный пример. Сейчас ошибка вполне может быть как раз в DAO и контроллерах.

Comment: Если убрать только @JsonProperty("names") List<String> names из сигнатуры контроллера, то все работает как должно.